# Using compressor as vacuum pump

Tags: pressure, vacuum

Why is it that a typical auto-shop compressor can easily fill big truck tires to +80 psi, but when used as a vacuum pump the same motor/valves can typically only pull -12psi or so of vacuum?

Comment: Actually, you only need to pull about -14.7 psi to reach full vacuum. Atmospheric pressure is only 14.7 psi, so once you've pulled -14.7 psi with a pump you've reached zero pressure and that's as low as you can go.

Comment: Sorry, got my units confused. A compressor pulling vacuum usually tops out at -25inHg, which is about -12.2psi. That's fine for, say, vacuum sealing food or de-gassing silicone, but not enough for, say, freeze-drying.

Comment: Well, pulling a good vacuum (trying to get as many gas molecules as possible out of a container) and gas compression (trying to get a lot of gas molecules into a container) are two very different things. One problem is that oils and other fluids can readily vaporize when the gas pressure gets low. Also, rubber and other components can outgas into the pump as the pressure gets low. The air outside the pump is also always trying to make its way into the vacuum pump and container. In sum, there are a lot of issues involved in creating a good vacuum that aren't a concern when compressing gas.

Comment: What Samuel said, so this is more of an engineering question than a physics question. But it's nice to see your good self posting on SE Physics. :)

Comment: @samuelweir, why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @nielsnielsen - Yeah, I'll try to remember next time to stop and think if a comment should really be posted as a answer.

Comment: @samuelweir, you deserve the points, after all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Samuel Weir:

> Well, pulling a good vacuum (trying to get as many gas molecules as possible out of a container) and gas compression (trying to get a lot of gas molecules into a container) are two very different things. One problem is that oils and other fluids can readily vaporize when the gas pressure gets low. Also, rubber and other components can outgas into the pump as the pressure gets low. The air outside the pump is also always trying to make its way into the vacuum pump and container. In sum, there are a lot of issues involved in creating a good vacuum that aren't a concern when compressing gas.

Comment: If Samuel decides to post himself his answer, and I'm warned about it, I'll delete this post.